# How can I specify a cluster CIDR when using kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I am a little unsure about how to ensure I do not have overlapping CIDRs when using kops to create multiple clusters.

I know it's possible to specify the `--cluster-cidr` when using the [kube-control-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager/), but I can't seem to find a way of doing this when using kops.

Answer (score 3):

First you check which CIDRs you are already using

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -cr '.Vpcs[] | [.CidrBlock, .VpcId, .Tags[0].Value]'
```

Than before you create the cluster, edit the main config

```
kops edit cluster $NAME
```

Change networkCIDR, nonMasqueradeCIDR and subnets.cidr

Note that subnets.cidr MUST be inside networkCIDR range.

Also note that networkCIDR and nonMasqueradeCIDR MUST NOT overlap

Example of valid config:

```
  networkCIDR: 10.80.0.0/16
  nonMasqueradeCIDR: 10.81.0.0/16
  subnets:
  - cidr: 10.80.0.0/24
```

Comment: if you want to peer two VPCs I know it is necessary to changes subnets to avoid overlapping, is it also necessary to change nonMasqueradeCIDR in this case ? I am not sure what the goal of that parameter

Comment: if you want to route pod traffic cross cluster, nonMasqCIDR should not overlap either (i believe)